# $_GET didn't not print out # symbol and text behind

Tags: php

i have a string send by `$_GET['foo']="C# Programmer";`

when I echo `$_GET['foo']`, it only print **C**

is any way to solve this problem when string container # or other symbols send by $_GET

Comment: urlencode your values before sending them to PHP

Comment: Works fine fore me...

Comment: How do you send it? What you do here, you just assign the value, which should work.

Comment: i set it by get, foo=C# Programmer

Comment: You should never be setting `$_GET` manually.  You're definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: @Izkata: I don't think the OP's setting `$_GET` manually. He probably meant the value of `$_GET['foo']` is equal to `C# Programmer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces and hashes (`#`) are not valid in HTTP URLs and will need to be encoded if you want to use it in parameter values. You can use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) to create URL-safe paramter values.

The following should work:

```
foo=C%23%20Programmer
```

If you're trying to send the `GET` request from a different page, you'd want something like this:

```
<?php 
$var = 'C# Programmer'; 
?>
<a href="select.php?foo=<?php echo urlencode($var) ?>"> Go </a>
```

Now, in `select.php`, if you try to `echo $_GET['foo'];`, it'll display `C# Programmer`.

Comment: if i use urlencode, do i must decode after it reach the page?

Comment: i did the testing, it works fine without decode, but i was wondering what is decode for?

Comment: @AmalMurali: What if the GET request is from the same page? In that case I think my answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of functions like urlencode for passing this kind of values, and urldecode to get this values. Try to make use of `post` method to avoid this kind of problems

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use the function named urlencode which returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs.

```
<?php 
$var = 'C# Programmer'; 
?>  <!-- end of PHP code -->
<a href="select.php?foo=
<?php echo urlencode($var) ?>  <!-- start and end of PHP code -->
"> Go </a>
```

[Live example](http://codepad.org/FxMaasCA)

For more information, read about [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: What does comments have to do with anything?

Comment: Amal, my mistake. fixed.

Comment: You need to urlencode the query parameters *before* sending the request, not after. So, this won't work.

Comment: Now this is just a copy of my answer.